# How to update quantity on basket on REACT table like below?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I have been trying without any luck, my implementation inside the Update method is not updating the state of products. Please assist with what am I doing wrong. I am using Functional Components with Hooks.

```
function MyTable() {
  const initState = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", quantitiy: 50, location: "cupboard" },
    { id: 2, name: "milk", quantitiy: 20, location: "fridge" },
    { id: 3, name: "water", quantitiy: 10, location: "fridge" }
  ];
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState);

  const handleUpdateQuantity = (productId: any, value: any) => {
    let newData = data;
    var index: number = newData.findIndex(
      (product: any) => product.id === productId
    )

    if (index !== -1) {
      newData[index].quantity = value
      setData(newData)
    } else {
      console.log("Product not existing on table data...")
    }
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <tr key={"header"}>
        {Object.keys(state[0]).map((key) => (
          <th>{key}</th>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.location}</td>
            <TextField
                type="number"
                defaultValue={1}
                onChange={(event) =>
                    handleUpdateQuantity(item.id, event.target.value)
                }
            />
          <td>{item.quantitiy}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyTable />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a functional update(as the new state depends on the previous state):

```
const handleUpdateQuantity = (productId: any, value: any) => {
    setData(prevData => prevData.map(el => {
        if(el.id === productId) {
            return {...el, quantity: value};
        }
        return el;
    }))
}
```

Also, `quantitiy`s in the initial state has a typo.

and in the JSX, add value prop to the text field:

```
<TextField
    type="number"
    defaultValue={1}
    value={item.quantity}
    onChange={(event) =>
        handleUpdateQuantity(item.id, event.target.value)
    }
/>
```

Comment: :D : D : ) I have tried this more than one day and failed and I have been always having a back mind that I will get it but still failed. Thank you soooooooo much, my Sir. You saved me a lot, I was so stressed, I would log this and get the correct value but yet State not getting updated : )